# Selecting a feature using expression if attribute field is "NULL"

Tags: qgis, expression

I am new to QGIS and am having, what I expect to be, an easy issue. I am working with a multi-polygon shapefile of taxable property parcels in QGIS 3.16.

All it is I am trying to do is select all features whose "FieldA" is empty (or "Null")

In the expression field I have tried: `"FieldA" = 0`; or `"FieldA" = NULL`

Neither of these work obviously and I am at a bit of an impasse.

Comment: `FieldA IS NULL` is the SQL standard, though shapefiles don't support NULLs, so if it's a text field, then `FieldA = ''`

Answer (score 3):

Use `"FieldA" is NULL` to select the features whose `FieldA`  is `NULL`. If the field type is string, then you also should use `"FieldA" = ''` to select the features whose `FieldA`  is empty. In QGIS, being empty doesn't mean being `NULL`.

And use `"FieldA" is NULL or "FieldA" = ''` to select all `NULL` and empty.